# import statement broken from migration 1.0.3 to 1.1 or higher

Tags: requirejs, typescript, amd

Using typescript in AMD modes the import statement is broken from version 1.0.3 to 1.1.

Directory structure:

- BatteryIncluded/TextWriter.ts
- BatteryIncluded/Registry.ts

Code Registry.ts:

```
import TextWriter = require("BatteryIncluded/TextWriter");

class Registry <ValueType> {
   // etc...
}

export = Registry;
```

Code TextWriter.ts:

```
class TextWriter {
   // etc..
}

export = TextWriter;
```

In typescript version 1.0.3 the error would not occur. But in version 1.1 or higher the error is:

```
"C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe" C:\PROJECT_GIT\TypeScript\built\local\tsc.js --sourcemap --    target ES5 --module AMD Registry.ts
Registry.ts(2,29): error TS2307: Cannot find external module 'BatteryIncluded/TextWriter'.
```

Using typescript in the form of:

```
node C:\PROJECT_GIT\TypeScript\built\local\tsc.js --sourcemap --target ES5 --module AMD $FileName$
```

---

To fix this problem i can use the import statement:

```
import TextWriter = require("./TextWriter");
```

This is not desired because all deeply nested files i need to do something like this:

```
import TextWriter = require("../../../TextWriter");
```

Before could just use:

```
import TextWriter = require("BatteryIncluded/TextWriter");
```

I have searched on TypeScript GitHub repro for release changes that could imply this error, but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

I have just downloaded TypeScript 1.1 to test this and it works file for me - the only difference I have is that my entry point is `app.ts` in the root, which loads `BatteryIncluded/Registry` which in turn loads `BatteryIncluded/TextWriter` and it all compiles fine.

I thought that maybe if you pointed the compiler at `BatteryIncluded/Registry` it might assume that this is the root, which would then make the path invalid. I tested this theory and it compiled fine for me also.

The only remaining difference is that I'm compiling from the command line.

[Here are the files I used](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/cmsfiles/assets/File/js/Nested-Example.zip) - perhaps you could give them a go to see if you get any issues (the nested folder name in this example is `Nested`).